# Make Data Type of Kind * -> * That's Not a Functor

Tags: haskell, functor

Brent Yorgey's [Typeclassopedia](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia) gives the following exercise:

> Give an example of a type of kind `* -> *` which cannot be made an 
>   instance of `Functor` (without using `undefined`).

Please tell me what "*cannot be made an instance of `Functor`*" means.

Also, I'd appreciate an example, but perhaps as a spoiler so that you can, please, guide me to the answer.

Comment: A functor `f` has `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, which satisfies `fmap x . fmap y = fmap (x . y)`.  Come up with a type where (1) you can't define `fmap`, or where (2) you can define `fmap` but can't make it follow the rule.

Comment: Hint: a common type of functor is a container, so if you invent a new kind of container it will probably be a functor.  Try creating a type `X a` such that `X a` doesn't contain an `a`, but perhaps does something else with `a`.

Comment: I'll add to @DietrichEpp's hint by reminding you that Haskell is a _function_-al language.  Give you any ideas?

Comment: so on #haskell IRC I got a hint, i.e. answer - `data Foo a = Foo (a -> a)` What would the type signature be for `fmap`-ing over `Foo (a -> a)` look like for `f b`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith : that's fine. Can you use an `a -> b` to turn a `Foo a` into a `Foo b`? Equivalently: what function has signature `(a -> b) -> (a -> a) -> b -> b`? Since we don't actually get an `a`, we have nothing to apply those first two functions to, so the only option is `const (const id) ≡ \_ _ b -> b`. But this violates a fundamental law, that `fmap id ≡ id`, because `const (const id) id ≡ const id` is not `id`. Another example is `data Foo x = Foo (x -> Int)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's talk about variances.

Here's the basic notion. Consider the type `A -> B`. What I want you to imagine is that such a type is similar to "having a `B`" and also "owing an `A`". In fact, if you pay back your `A` you immediately receive your `B`. Functions are kind of like escrow in that way.

The notion of "having" and "owing" can extend to other types. For instance, the simplest container

```
newtype Box a = Box a
```

behaves like this: if you "have" a `Box a` then you also "have" an `a`. We consider types which have kind `* -> *` and "have" their argument to be (covariant) functors and we can instantiate them to `Functor`

```
instance Functor Box where fmap f (Box a) = Box (f a)
```

What happens if we consider the type of predicates over a type, like

```
newtype Pred a = Pred (a -> Bool)
```

in this case, if we "have" a `Pred a`, we actually "owe" an `a`. This arises from the `a` being on the left side of the `(->)` arrow. Where `fmap` of `Functor` is defined by passing the function into the container and applying it to all the places where we "have" our inner type, we can't do the same for `Pred a` since we don't "have" and `a`s.

Instead, we'll do this

```
class Contravariant f where
  contramap :: (a -> b) -> (f b -> f a)
```

Now that `contramap` is like a "flipped" `fmap`? It will allow us to apply the function to the places where we "own" a `b` in `Pred b` in order to receive a `Pred a`. We might call `contramap` "barter" because it encodes the idea that if you know how to get `b`s from `a`s then you can turn a debt of `b`s into a debt of `a`s.

Let's see how it works

```
instance Contravariant Pred where
  contramap f (Pred p) = Pred (\a -> p (f a))
```

we just run our trade using `f` prior to passing it on into the predicate function. Wonderful!

So now we have covariant and contravariant types. Technically, these are known as covariant and contravariant "functors". I'll also state immediately that almost always a contravariant functor is not also covariant. This, thus, answers your question: there exist a bunch of contravariant functors which are not able to be instantiated to `Functor`. `Pred` is one of them.

There are tricky types which are both contravariant and covariant functors, though. In particular, the constant functors:

```
data Z a = Z -- phantom a!

instance Functor       Z where fmap      _ Z = Z
instance Contravariant Z where contramap _ Z = Z
```

In fact, you can essentially prove that anything which is both `Contravariant` and `Functor` has a phantom parameter.

```
isPhantom :: (Functor f, Contravariant f) => f a -> f b   -- coerce?!
isPhantom = contramap (const ()) . fmap (const ())        -- not really...
```

On the other hand, what happens with a type like

```
-- from Data.Monoid
newtype Endo a = Endo (a -> a)
```

In `Endo a` we both owe and receive an `a`. Does that mean we're debt free? Well, no, it just means that `Endo` wants to be both covariant and contravariant *and* does not have a phantom parameter. The result: `Endo` is *invariant* and can instantiate neither `Functor` nor `Contravariant`.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer.  Why can't Pred be a Functor?  Why can't we owe an 'a' via fmap's first argument?

Comment: Essentially it all just boils down to the "direction" of `fmap` and `contramap`. Since `fmap` maps "in the same direction" (e.g. `a -> b` becomes `f a -> f b`) then it only works when "having an `f a`" lets us "have" an `a`. Conversely, since contramap maps "in the opposite direction" (e.g. `a -> b` becomes `f b -> f a`) then it works when "having" an `f b` is the same as "owing" a `b`.

Comment: I re-read your answer two more times. So, for `Pred (a -> Boolean)`, we cannot write an `fmap` instance: `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` since `applying` the function, `a -> b`, to `Pred`, would give a `Pred Boolean`, not a `Pred b`?

Comment: It's that applying the function `a -> b` to `Pred a` is poorly typed. Applying, by which we mean `contramap`ping a function `a -> b` to `Pred b` (!) gives you `Pred a`.

Answer (score 12):

A type `t` of kind `* -> *` can be made an instance of `Functor` if and only if it is possible to implement a law-abiding instance of the `Functor` class for it.  So that means you have to implement the `Functor` class, and your `fmap` has to obey the `Functor` laws:

```
fmap id x == x
fmap f (fmap g x) == fmap (f . g) x
```

So basically, to solve this, you have to name some type of your choice and prove that there's no lawful implementation of `fmap` for it.

Let's start with a *non*-example, to set the tone.  `(->) :: * -> * -> *` is the function type constructor, as seen in function types like `String -> Int :: *`.  In Haskell, you can partially apply type constructors, so you can have types like `(->) r :: * -> *`.  This type is a `Functor`:

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap f g = f . g
```

Intuitively, the `Functor` instance here allows you to apply `f :: a -> b` to the return value of a function `g :: r -> a` "before" (so to speak) you apply `g` to some `x :: r`.  So for example, if this is the function that returns the length of its argument:

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

...then this is the function that returns twice the length of its argument:

```
twiceTheLength :: [a] -> Int
twiceTheLength = fmap (*2) length
```

Useful fact: the `Reader` monad is just a `newtype` for `(->)`:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }

instance Functor (Reader r) where
    fmap f (Reader g) = Reader (f . g)

instance Applicative (Reader r) where
    pure a = Reader (const a)
    Reader f <*> Reader a = Reader $ \r -> f r (a r)

instance Monad (Reader r) where
    return = pure
    Reader f >>= g = Reader $ \r -> runReader g (f r) r
```

Now that we have that non-example out of the way, here's a type that can't be made into a `Functor`:

```
type Redaer a r = Redaer { runRedaer :: r -> a } 

-- Not gonna work!
instance Functor (Redaer a) where
    fmap f (Redaer g) = ...
```

Yep, all I did is spell the name backwards, and more importantly, flip the order of the type parameters.  I'll let you try and figure out why this type can't be made an instance of `Functor`.

Comment: and when you've figured that out, check out [contravariant functors and bifunctors](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/liyang/profunctors)