# Haskell type functions?

Tags: haskell, types

Consider this ADT:

```
data Property f a = Property String (f a) | Zilch
  deriving Show
```

What is `f` here? Is it a function acting on `a`? Is it a 'type function'? The instructor said that Haskell has a Turing complete type language...so in which case the types can have functions too I assume?

```
*Main> var = Property "Colors" [1,2,3,4]
*Main> :t var
var :: Num a => Property [] a
```

How is `f` behaving like `[]` here? Since `[]` is the constructor for the empty list, is `f` always going to be the outermost empty constructor for the type of `a` as in the following examples?

```
*Main> var = Property "Colors" [(1,"Red"),(2,"Blue")]
*Main> :t var
var :: Num t => Property [] (t, [Char])

*Main> var = Property "Colors" (1,"Red")
*Main> :t var
var :: Num t => Property ((,) t) [Char]
```

The latter one I don't quite get but if someone said Haskell inferred the empty constructor for that tuple, I'm okay buying that. On the other hand,

```
*Main> var = Property "Colors" 20
*Main> :t var
var :: Num (f a) => Property f a
```

what is `f` here? Can't be the identity because `id :: a -> a` but we need `(f a)`.

I managed to make my ADT a functor with:

```
instance Functor f => Functor (Property f) where
  fmap fun (Property name a) = Property name (fmap fun a)
  fmap g Zilch               = Zilch
```

So something like the following works

```
*Main> var = Property "Colors" [1,2,3,4]
*Main> fmap (+1) var
Property "Colors" [2,3,4,5]
```

But what if I gave it to the previous example of a tuple?

I am really looking for explanatory answers (have seen Haskell for barely two months in a summer course), not references to things like `FlexibleContexts` to allow ... say `fmap` to work on arbitrary `a`.

Comment: Haskells type system is *not* Turing complete. There are extensions in GHC to make it Turing complete.

Comment: re: `Property "Colors" (1,"Red")` , try `:t (1,3) :: ((,) Int) Integer` at GHCi prompt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've gotten confused by the (confusing) fact that `[]` means two different things in different contexts in Haskell, which has made it hard for you to interpret the rest of your experiments.

At the value level `[]` indeed is the empty constructor for lists. But when you asked for the type of `Property "Colors" [1,2,3,4]` and saw `Property [] a` you're looking at a **type** expression, not a value expression. There is no empty list at the type level.<sup>1</sup> Instead `[]` is the *type constructor* for the list type. You can have `[Int]` (the type of lists of ints), `[Bool]` (the type of lists of bools), or `[a]` (the polymorphic type of lists of `a`); `[]` is the thing that's being applied to `Int`, `Bool`, and `a` in those examples.

You can actually write `[Int]` as `[] Int` if you want, though it looks weird, so you usually only see `[]` at the type level when you want to use it unapplied.

Lets take a look at your data declaration again:

```
data Property f a = Property String (f a) | Zilch
```

On the left-hand side you've declared the shape of the **type** `Property`; `Property f a` forms a type. On the right hand side you declare the shape of the **values** that go in that type, by listing the possible value constructors (`Property` and `Zilch`) and the types of the "slots" in those constructors (none for `Zilch`; one slot of type `String` and another one of type `f a`, for `Property`).

So from that we can tell that whatever `f` and `a` are, the type expression `f a` (`f` applied to `a`) must form a type that has values. But `f` doesn't have to be (in fact it can't be) a normal type of values on its own! There is no slot of type `f` in the `Property` value constructor.

A much clearer example to use would have been this:

```
*Main> var = Property "Stuff" (Just True)
*Main> :t var
var :: Property Maybe Bool
```

If you don't know it, `Maybe` is a built in type whose declaration looks like this:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

It's good for this example because we're not using the same name at the type level and the value level, which avoids confusion when you're trying to learn how things work.

`Just True` is a value of type `Maybe Bool`. At the value level we have the `Just` data constructor applied to the value `True`. At the type level we have the `Maybe` *type constructor* applied to the type `Bool`. `Maybe Bool` values go in the `f a` slot of the `Property` value constructor, which fits straightforwardly: `f` is `Maybe` and `a` is `Bool`.

So going back to your original example:

```
*Main> var = Property "Colors" [1,2,3,4]
*Main> :t var
var :: Num a => Property [] a
```

You're filling the `f a` slot with `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. That's a list of some kind of number, so it'll be `Num t => [t]`. So the `a` in `f a` is the `t` (with a `Num` constraint that needs to come along), and the `f` is the **list type constructor** `[]`. This `[]` is like `Maybe`, not like `Nothing`.

```
*Main> var = Property "Colors" (1,"Red")
*Main> :t var
var :: Num t => Property ((,) t) [Char]
```

Here the `f a` slot is being filled with `(1, "Red")`, which is of type `Num t => (t, [Char])` (remembering that `String` is just another way of writing `[Char]`). Now to understand this we have to get a little finicky. Forget the constraint for now, and just focus on `(t, [Char])`. Somehow we need to interpret that as something applied to something else, so we can match it to `f a`. Well it turns out that although we have special *syntax* for tuple types (like `(a, b)`), they're really just like ordinary ADTs you could declare without the special syntax. A 2-tuple type is a type constructor that we can write `(,)` applied to two other types, in this case `t` and `[Char]`. And we can use partially applied type constructors, so we can think of `(,)` applied to `t` as one unit, and that unit applied to `[Char]`. We can write that interpretation as a Haskell type expression `((,) t) [Char]`, but I'm not sure if that's clearer. But what it comes down to is that we can match this to `f a` by taking the first "unit" `(,) t` as `f` and `[Char]` as `a`. Which then gives us `Property ((,) t) [Char]` (only we have to also put back the `Num t` constraint we forgot about earlier).

And finally this one:

```
*Main> var = Property "Colors" 20
*Main> :t var
var :: Num (f a) => Property f a
```

Here we're filling the `f a` slot with `20`, some sort of number. We haven't specified exactly what type the number is, so Haskell is willing to believe it could be any type in the `Num` class. But we still need the type to have a "shape" we can match with `f a`: some type constructor applied to some other type. And it's the whole type expression `f a` that needs to match the type of `20`, so *that's* what has a `Num` constraint. But we haven't said anything else about what `f` or `a` might be, and `20` can by *any* type that meets a `Num` constraint, so it can be any `Num (f a) => f a` we want for it, hence why the type of your `var` is still polymorphic in `f` and `a` (just with the added constraint).

You might have only seen numeric types like `Integer`, `Int`, `Double`, etc, and so be wondering how there could possibly be an `f a` that's a number; all of those examples are just single basic types, not something applied to something. But you can write your own `Num` instances, so Haskell never assumes a given type (or shape of type) *couldn't* be a number, it'll just complain if you actually attempt to use it and it can't find a `Num` instance. So sometimes you get things like this that are *probably* errors, but Haskell accepts (for now) with a `Num` type on an odd thing that you weren't expecting.

And in fact there *are* already types in the built-in libraries that do have compound type-level structore and have a `Num` instance. One example is the `Ratio` type for representing fractional numbers as ratios of two integers. You can have a `Ratio Int` or a `Ratio Integer`, for example:

```
Main*> 4 :: Ratio Int
4 % 1
```

So you could say:

```
*Main> var = Property "Colors" (20 :: Ratio Integer)
*Main> :t var
var :: Property Ratio Integer
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually there can be, with the `DataKinds` extension enabled to allow types that mirror the structure of almost any value, so you can have type-level lists. But that's not what's going on here and it's not really a feature you can use until you've got a good handle on the way types and values work in vanilla Haskell, so I recommend you ignore this footnote and pretend it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: This is a great answer and much appreciated. Clearly I have a lot of reading/ways to go. If someone could touch upon what happened when I constrained the `type function` `f` to be a `functor` it would be perfect.

Answer (score 7):

> What is `f` here? Is it a function acting on `a`? Is it a 'type function'?

Yes, it is indeed a type function, in the sense that it accepts a type and yields a type, i.e. its *kind* is `Type -> Type` – or, as Haskell traditionally writes it

```
> :k []
[] :: * -> *
```

> How is `f` behaving like `[]` here? Since `[]` is the constructor for the empty list...

That's a misunderstanding. Actually there are two different things called `[]` in Haskell:

2. The list *value constructor* `[] :: [a]`. This generates an empty list (or arbitrary contained-type – since it actually contains zero elements anyway you don't care about that type).

and

1. The list *type constructor* `[] :: * -> *`. This takes a *type* and gives the type of a list containing values of that type. The argument is important, because most interesting lists are obviously *not* empty.

In `Property [] a`, you're dealing with the type constructor, which again, unlike the value constructor, is a function which operates on types, therefore you can instantiate it for `f`.

> `Property ((,) t) [Char]`

Here you've discovered another type-level function: the tuple type constructor. This takes two type arguments and gives a type (that of tuples of these types). With `(,) t` you already apply it to one type argument, but leave the other open, so again you can use this as a one-argument type function like `f`.

Answer (score 4):

> The instructor said that Haskell has a Turing complete type language...

First of all that claim is wrong. Haskell has no Turing complete type system. There are *extensions* in GHC to make it Turing complete, but pure Haskell has not Turing complete type system.

> How is `f` behaving like `[]` here? Since `[]` is the constructor for the empty list, is `f` always going to be the outermost empty constructor for the type of a as in the following examples?

You are mixing type constructors with value constructors. Haskell has defined a list as:

```
data [] a = [] | a : ([] a)
```

The boldface is the **`[]` type constructor** the non-boldface is the value constructor. If you write **`[]`** in a type signature you refer to the type. For instance `map` has type `map :: (a -> b) -> [] a -> [] b`.

Now as we have seen in the definition of `data []`, we have a **type parameter**. We need to apply the `[]` type to another type before it is a "concrete" type. Therefore the "meta-type" of `[]` is `* -> *`: it takes.

The same holds for the type `Property`, it has meta-type `* -> * -> *` since it requires two type parameters. `Property []` on the other hand has meta-type `* -> *`.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134825/how-do-functors-work-in-haskell) and [kinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985562/make-data-type-of-kind-thats-not-a-functor):

The `f` there is *like* a functor, (but it's not a functor) meaning in first place that the type of the type `f` (the type of a type is named `kind` in haskell), is `* -> *`, meaning it takes a type, and returns a type to you.

That's why `var = Property "Colors" [1,2,3,4]`, `var` has that "rare" type not because `[]` is the empty constructor of list, is because `[] :k` is `* -> *`

Let's see this another example:

```
var2 = Property "Perhaps A Bool" (Just True)
```

type of `var2 :t` :

```
var2 :: Property Maybe Bool
```

Why is that, because Maybe also has kind *->*, it is waiting for a type to return another, see the type, **it doesn't say** `(Maybe Bool) Bool` **it says** `Maybe Bool`. Just as your another example, like `[]` instead `[Int]`

More about [functors](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) and [kinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095011/what-exactly-is-the-kind-in-haskell)

Comment: The `f` need not be a `Functor`. For example, `Property "functions" [Endo id]` is perfectly well-typed.

Comment: @DanielWagner you meant `Property "functions" (Endo id)`. :)

Comment: @DanielWagner you are right, thanks for the wise comment, I appreciate, if you want take another look to my edit please

Comment: @WillNess what's the difference between endo id, or [endo id]? (I updated the answer, If you want to take another look! thanks

Comment: `Property "functions" [Endo id] :: Property [] (Endo a)` and `[]` is a Functor, so that's no counter-example. `Property "functions" (Endo id) :: Property Endo a` and `Endo` is *not* a Functor.

Comment: `data Property f a = Property String (f a)` means there's a function `Property :: String -> f a -> Property f a`, the so called data constructor for the type `Property f a` where `f :: * -> *`. this means `Property ("x" :: String) (Just True :: Maybe Bool) :: Property Maybe Bool` i.e. `f` was matched with `Maybe` and `a` with `Bool`. In "open formulas" like `(x + 3)` it is not clear how to interpret the free variable `x`. Lambda expressions like `\x -> x + 3` make `x` a *bound* variable, i.e. they provide a binding for it. Same with `data` declarations, on type level. `Prop Str (f a)` has two

Comment: two free type variables. What are they? how can they be interpreted? not clear. `data Property (f :: * -> *) a` provides type-level binding for these type variables, `f`, and `a`. it's nothing, really. It's just saying, "look out, in the following open formula there are two type variables in play, and we'll take care of them later". So we can ask *"what's the `f` in the type of `Property "x" (Just True)`?"* and answer *"it's `Maybe`"*.

Comment: glad to help. pass it forward. :)